# Do I really need Adobe Premier Elements Plus if all I care about is the 'extra' content? (Themes, effects, etc)

Tags: video, adobe-premiere

I'd like to purchase Adobe Premier Elements, but I don't want to spend an extra $50 if I don't need to for the "Plus" version.  These are the things that it includes (that the regular supposedly doesn't provide):

- Get exclusive access to libraries of creative Plus extras
- Get cinematic inspiration with movie themes, special effects, and more delivered regularly to your software
- Get help with regular deliveries of easy-to-use how-tos

**I don't care** about their online storage, **I don't care** about the 'how-tos', or updates being regularly 'delivered' to the software.  **I DO care** about the extra special effects, themes, and other content, **my question is are these things I care about free and accessible somewhere?** (It almost sounds like these stuff would be free, just not 'automatically' available in the software, just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

There are templates available elsewhere, but if you want the ones that they are delivering, then you need to be a Plus member.

See ProDesign Tools for [direct download links](http://prodesigntools.com/photoshop-elements-9-premiere-elements-9-direct-download-links.html) of some templates. You need to open a free Adobe account, and login in another window to use the links. See directions on the linked page.